# c++ standard section id where its mentioned that Destructors are implicitly no throw

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, destructor, language-lawyer

I read somewhere that since c++11, the destructors are implicitly declared `noexcept(true)`.

From the standard section 12.4

> A declaration of a destructor that does not have an
>   exception-specification has the same exception specification as if had
>   been implicitly declared

But nowhere in the standard could I find a section where in it says that destructors are implicitly `noexcept(true)`. Can anyone point me to the section where I can find this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for §15.4/14 (emphasis mine):

> An inheriting constructor (12.9) and an implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) have an
>   exception-specification. If `f` is an inheriting constructor or an implicitly declared default constructor, copy
>   constructor, move constructor, **destructor**, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   exception-specification specifies the type-id `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the exception-specification
>   of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly
>   invokes allows all exceptions, and f has the exception-specification noexcept(true) if every function it directly
>   invokes allows no exceptions. *[ Note:* **It follows that `f` has the exception-specification `noexcept(true)`
>   if it invokes no other functions**. *—end note ]*

Comment: Interesting note there, it's not in the official, final C++11 standard. Did you look at a later or an earlier draft?

Comment: This is from N4140, but the same appears in N3690 as well (just checked).

Comment: @Barry, this is still a deduction, but not an actual line in the standard which says that destructors are noexcept(true)....  I suppose thats the way things are specified in the standard after all :-) ... btw i am refering to N4296

Comment: @Arun See the note. An implicit destructor invokes no other functions, therefore it is `noexcept(true)` [unless one of its members or bases isn't]. It is written this way to include all the special member functions in one go. Destructors are not special in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

The description of how a special member's implicit exception specification is formed is in 15.4/14.  It's not very clear, but it basically says that a special member **only** throws those exceptions thrown by the special members of the bases and members it calls; this implies that a) if there are no bases or members, there won't be any exceptions, and b) if all bases and members don't throw exceptions, there won't be any exceptions. The end result is that destructors are `noexcept(true)` unless any member or base's destructor is not.